Nodemailer timed Out Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 64.233.184.109:587 errno: -4039,
Error in sending Email through Node mailer.
Everything in the code is right but it is giving error of timedOut
I am aready using App Password generated by google account
Below is my function
The Host and port are
SMTP_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
SMTP_PORT=587

``

    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: process.env.SMTP_HOST,
    port: process.env.SMTP_PORT,
    secure: false, // Use `true` for port 465, `false` for all other ports
    auth: {
    user: process.env.SMTP_MAIL,
    pass: process.env.SMTP_PASSWORD,
  },
});


app.post("/sendEmail", async (req, res) => {
  const { email, subject, message } = req.body;
  console.log(email, subject, message);

  var mailOptions = {
    from: process.env.SMTP_MAIL,
    to: email,
    subject: subject,
    text: message,
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log("Email sent successfully!");
    }
  });
});

`
`

The response it is giving is
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 64.233.184.109:587
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1595:16) {
errno: -4039,
code: 'ESOCKET',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '64.233.184.109',
port: 587,
command: 'CONN'
}
I have tried changing port and host but each time it is giving the same error.
I don't think there is any mistake in the code but some port or host or something like that is causing problem

have you enabled 2 step verificaion for you google account?

Yes I have enabled 2 step verification
